# Mutex lock in Node.js using PM2

Tags: node.js, mutex, pm2

We have an item with a quantity of 1,000. As soon as we put it on sale, people can purchase it at the same time. I was worried that the system would still allow users to pay although there were no more items left. So I came across reading about mutex to avoid race condition.

Node.js

```
import { Mutex } from 'async-mutex'

const mutex = new Mutex();

async function buyItem() {
  const release = await mutex.acquire();
  try {
    const balance = await loadBalance();
    if (balance > 0) {
      await userPay();
      await updateBalance();
    }
  } finally {
    release();
  }
}
```

I believe the above snippets can help users avoid unwanted outcomes, but the real concern is how we can adjust that in pm2 envinronment with multiple clusters. I could not find any solid answer to this. I use PostgreSQL and prisma. Any example or help is appreciated!